# GCC complains on str not able to be NULL

Tags: c, gcc-warning

I have the following code:

```
int atoi(const char * str)
{
    int ret = 0, i;
    if (str) {
            for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
                    if (str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9')
                            ret = ret * 10 + str[i] - '0';
    }   
    return ret;
}
```

when trying to compile it with

```
fug@fugtop ~/p/book> make
gcc -c -o db.o db.c -Wall -Werror -std=c99 -g -DVERSION=\"v0.4\"  -Wno-
unused-variable -Wno-unused-function
gcc -c -o misc.o misc.c -Wall -Werror -std=c99 -g -DVERSION=\"v0.4\"  -
Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-function
misc.c: In function ‘atoi’:
misc.c:55:5: error: nonnull argument ‘str’ compared to NULL [-Werror=nonnull-compare]
  if (str) {
     ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
Makefile:54: recipe for target 'misc.o' failed
make: *** [misc.o] Error 1
```

I'm using the gcc version:

```
fug@fugtop ~/p/book> gcc --version
gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18) 6.3.0 20170516
```

I don't understand the warning. A const char * should be able to be NULL, right?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but your function have a serious flaw... Try using e.g. `"123abc456"` as input and see what the result will be.

Comment: Probably `gcc` tries to inline that function and knows that there is no NULL arguments passed to it. How many times this function is used in your code and what are the examples of its usage?

Comment: Seems like a false positive. Although `if(str)` is sloppy style compared to `if(str != NULL)`, there's not really a need to toss a warning for that.

Comment: @myaut Doesn't seem like any optimization is enabled though? There's no `-O` options passed so it shouldn't do inlining.

Comment: `atoi` is the problem here, you should choose another name.

Comment: @Lundin This is a good reason to point, why one should never use names in their functions which are already exists.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`atoi` is a standard function in the c library.  The header for that standard function contains the attribute `__nonnull`, which triggers special gcc handling.

Your overridden implementation doesn't make use of that special handling (honoring the assumption that the argument is not null), thus the warning.

The real answer: don't re-use a function name from a function from the standard library.

Comment: I cannot reproduce OP issue with gcc 6.1.2, but very good answer nonetheless (congrats for the 10k) !

Comment: Same, I can't reproduce this even when including stdlib.h.

Comment: I can reproduce by pasting the OP's code *and* adding an `#include <stdlib.h>`.  This is what is pulling in the `__nonnull` attribute for the glibc function.  Without that include, no problem.

Comment: I'm compiling that very same code with `-std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors` and I can't reproduce (using older 4.9.x version of gcc).

Comment: It only reproduces with gcc >= 6.1

Comment: using 6.2.1 here, and cannot reproduce. But your answer is valid. The `__nonnull` attribute guarantees that it cannot be null, so you have a warning. Makes sense. Maybe a gcc 6.1-only bug